# `Normalization of $\mathbb{P}^1_k $ in the fraction field of a hyperbola

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

(This is Ravi Vakil Exercise 9.7.L(b))

I’m trying to describe the normalization of $$\mathbb{P}^1_k = \operatorname{Spec}(k[x]) \cup \operatorname{Spec}(k[x^{-1}])$$ in the fraction field, $F$, of $$k[x,y]/(x^2+x-y^2).$$

The first part of the exercise had me prove $$k[x]\subset k[x,y]/(x^2+x-y^2)$$ is the normalization of the $\operatorname{Spec}(k[x]) $ piece. This was easy enough since the hyperbola $\operatorname{Spec} \big(k[x,y]/(x^2+x-y^2)\big)$ is isomorphic to an open subscheme of $\mathbb{P}^1_k$ and is therefore normal. But now for the other piece I guess I need to compute integral closure in $F$ of $k[x^{-1}]$ and then glue the two pieces, hopefully into something recognizable.

Any help with any of this is most welcome, especially just computing the integral closure of $k[x^{-1}]$ in the fraction field of $$k[x,y]/(x^2+x-y^2).$$

**Edit:** Following @TokenToucan 's helpful hint I found the integral closure of the $k[x^{-1}]$ to be $k[x^{-1},\frac{y}{x}]$ (in $F$), which (via $(x^{-1},\frac{y}{x}) \rightarrow (s,t)$) is isomorphic to $k[s,t]/(1+s-t^2)$, which (via $(s,t)\rightarrow (u^2-1,u)$) is isomorphic to $k[u].$  Similarly,  as noted above the integral closure of the $k[x]$ is $k[x,y]/(x^2+x-y^2)$ which (via $(2x+1-2y,2x+1+2y)\rightarrow (v,v^{-1})$) is isomorphic to $k[v]_v$. So the normalization is $$\operatorname{Spec}(k[u]) \cup \operatorname{Spec}(k[v]_v) $$ with the gluing $$k[u]_{u^2-1} \rightarrow (k[v]_{v})_{v+\frac{1}{v}-2},~~~~ u \mapsto \frac{v-1/v}{-2+v+1/v}. $$

In case $k=\mathbb{R}$, this gives the following picture of gluings [image]

So, **is this something recognizable**?  It seems a little like another copy of $\mathbb{P}^1$, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Please use \operatorname{Spec} to format $\operatorname{Spec}$. This makes it look much better, produces the correct spacing, etc. I've made this upgrade for you in this post.

Comment: If you rewrite the defining equations in $1/x$ then you can see that $y/x$ is in the integral closure, $k[y/x]$  contains $k[1/x]$, and $k[y/x]$ has the right fraction field. So I am guessing you can prove that $k[y/x]$ is the integral closure and you can check it is normal by checking it is isomorphic to a polynomial ring in 1 variable.

Comment: @TokenToucan ah, thanks so much.

Comment: Can I ask how you worked out the gluing?